# Distance between two points with MapKit WITHOUT euclidean distance calculation

Tags: swift, mapkit, cllocation, euclidean-distance

I have a game map that has been tiled over the world map of MapKit. I generate a path to take for the player. With this I find the 3 nearest nodes (in game cities) and select one at random then recurs this to find a 3rd node. I have some logic that means the chosen nodes at each stage aren't in any of the previous arrays to allow for a nice path and no "coming back on your self".

However, the issue I'm facing is I'm using `CLLocation.distance()`, this unfortunately uses an euclidean distance calculation due to the curvature of the earth. Is there any way to off set the curve as my current logic ends up in all paths slowly leaning towards the poles as the world map is just a flat image.

I've thought about translating CLLocation to a UIView between the first node and all possible second nodes, however this becomes massively intensive.

Any ideas on how to either offset the curve calulation or remove it all together?

Comment: The `distance` function calculates the distance based on the great circle distance between the two locations. Please clarify what distance you actually want between the two locations.

Comment: something more relative to the view of the screen so maybe pixel to pixel.